# Download file error with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have content that JS creates in a function and i need to print that content into my downloads folder but when i try to via ajax it will not work and is not throwing any errors

JS code

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'includes/download.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {'filename': name_file, 'content': content},
      success: function(data, status) {
        if(data == "ok") {
          console.log('data okay');
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    });
```

PHP code

```
<?
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$content = $_POST['content'];

header("Content-type: csd/");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);

print $content;
```

Comment: I believe I am either calling ajax incorrectly or sending data incorrectly, either way the JS is logging just the Details and error and none of the error variables.

Comment: Chk ending brackets `$_POST['filename']);` and `$_POST['content']);`

Comment: downloads folder **WHERE**? on your client? or on the server? because none of that code creates any files anywhere. you're simply sending some text to the server which then spits it right back at the client with a different mimetype/disposition.

Comment: downloads folder on the client, when i use that php code and manually input variables it created a file in the downloads folder on the client (also those brackets were a mistake I fixed it and now in the developers log it shows downloads.php with the content i want in the downloads folder)

Comment: Can you verify that the URL of `'includes/download.php'` is not throwing a 404 error?

Comment: it is not I believe it to be an error that doesn't allow for the header function to work, what would be common errors that would cause that but not throw an error code that upsets everything else?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the content in a javascript variable you don't need any ajax call to save it

```
var content = 'anything';
var filename = 'testFile.txt';
var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(content);
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = filename;
hiddenElement.click();
```

The `filename` variable should contain the extension as well

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w2sLq8pb/)**

Comment: I have tried that it does not save in the download it simply opens the content in a new window??

Comment: If I open the fiddle it automatically downloads a `file.txt` to my PC. Doesn't it download on your PC?

Comment: can you please edit the fiddle with your `content` variable for me too see the content that you try to save?

Comment: It opens a new window and downloads as Unknown not as my name_file name

Comment: It also only opens one window when I need to open 2 or more it is a loop that separates data and creates new files based on the data this is only downloading the first loop as the wrong file name as well.

Comment: I've edited my example if you run the code above in your browser console you should get a `testFile.txt` with the `anything` as content. In order for me to help you and fix you case I need to see your full code. The problem is not with the example above it's with your own case

Comment: Header will not work after any html data is open so that is why my content is not downloading, what would be the best way to fix this in my download.php file??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107178/discussion-between-sabbin-and-chouse95).